# Solving differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem with solving the following differential equation:
$(x^a u'(x))'=0$, where x and a are in $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$, respectively.The derivative given in equation is with respect to $x$. I used Mathematica and got the following solution:
$C_{2}+ (C_{1}/1-a)*x^(1-a)$.
But I didn't get it's detail. Could you please share detail for this solution or help me in getting step by step solution from Mathematica?

All the best,

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code (not an image) so that forum participants can study the problem and help you further. You can copy directly from the input cell and paste in the `Edit` window, There is a `{ ... }` icon to format it as code.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = D[x^a u'[x], x] == 0

(* a x^(-1 + a) u'[x] + x^a u''[x] == 0 *)

sol = DSolve[eqn, u, x][[1]]

(* {u -> Function[{x}, (x^(1 - a) C[1])/(1 - a) + C[2]]} *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
eqn /. sol

(* True *)

u[x] /. sol

(* (x^(1 - a) C[1])/(1 - a) + C[2] *)
```

`Mathematica` doesn't provide step-by-step solutions. However, it can be used to call `WolframAlpha` which does in some cases -- such as this

```
WolframAlpha["DSolve[a x^(a-1) u'[x] + x^a u''[x] == 0, u[x], x]"]
```

[image]